# 'Writing': is it a gerund (noun) or present participle (adjective) in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gerunds

What is 'writing' in these two sentences, a gerund or present participle (adjective): 1) "This is my writing table" and 2) "I bought a writing table"?

Comment: "Writing" is best classified as a verb phrase functioning as an attributive modifier, where it has a purposive meaning: "table for writing". Note that modern grammar does not distinguish gerunds and present participials, simply calling both _ing_ forms 'gerund-participials'.

Comment: @FumbleFingersThanks for sharing the link. It was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A *writing table* is a table for the purpose of writing on, not a table that is in the act of writing. *Writing* here is a gerund used as an adjective.

https://medium.com/@engtuto1/can-gerunds-be-also-used-as-adjectives-89e5698411f3

Comment: "Writing" fails all the usual tests for adjectivehood. It's actually a verb, where it has a purposive meaning: "table for writing".

Comment: Does that mean that the website is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. Here are two tests: (1) "writing" can't be modified by "very"; (2) "Writing" can’t occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like “become” (we can’t say *”It became became quite writing”) or complex-transitive verbs like “find” (we can’t say *”I found it quite writing). See my answer.

Comment: @BillJ please always try make reference to your answer. Your answers seem to be misleading. You may like to explore a bit more in any reputed grammar book. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @KateBunting  Finally someone has made my day, sharing the link. The best explanation. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Airforce What are you talking about? FYI, I teach English grammar and have studied the most advanced grammars available, both traditional and modern. The cited website is hardly scholarly or authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

> *This is my writing table*.
>
> *I bought a writing table*.

"Writing" is best classified as a verb phrase functioning as an attributive modifier.

It's clearly not a noun, and it fails the usual tests for adjectivehood. For example, it can't be modified by "very". And it can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" (we can’t say *"It became became quite writing") or complex-transitive verbs like "find" (we  can’t say *"I found it quite writing").

Compare this with, say "entertaining", which passes all the tests: "I found the show very entertaining" / "It became quite entertaining" / "I found it quite entertaining".

The range of expressions that can occur as pre-head modifier to a noun is very large and varied: we don't want to call them all adjectives. "Entertaining" has the properties of indisputable adjectives and hence must belong in that class, but others like "writing" don't have the distinctive properties of adjectives, and hence are best regarded as verbs.